# Error read_xlsx (v1.0): Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim, : std::bad_alloc

Tags: r, xlsx, hpc, readxl

I have Rstudio Version 1.1.447/R 3.4.4 on my Mac and have been running this code with no problems in my script:

```
NCBI16S<-read_xlsx("accession_taxon_16s.xlsx")
```

This is with `readxl` version 1.1.0.

I am using R/3.4.0 within a computer cluster (UMass GHPCC). This uses `readxl` version 1.0.0. I did try to reinstall a newer version of `readxl` and I thought it did based on this:

```
install.packages("readxl")
```

> Installing package into
>   ‘/home/gc54a/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) trying URL
>   'https://rweb.crmda.ku.edu/cran/src/contrib/**readxl_1.1.0.tar**.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2036680 bytes (1.9 MB)

But afterwards, with `sessionInfo(),` it says `readxl` is still version 1.0.0 - not sure why.

Anyway, on the HPCC R/3.4.0, I am using the same script and files imported onto my home directory but now am receiving an error:

> Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim =
>   shim,  :    std::bad_alloc

The accession_taxon_16s.xlsx has 856824 rows and two columns (NCBI ID and then sequence data).

I read previous discussions but they seemed to focus on .xls files (#373 , #432, #416) and once switched to .xlsx it worked fine and that .xlsx doesn't have the infinite loop problem like .xls files do.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do they have the same `readxl` version?

Comment: No, sorry - just realized one is 1.0 and one 1.1.0

Comment: Then you should update your question: which version worked or failed

Comment: Done! Hope this is more clear.

Comment: set `R_LIBS_USER` to a folder that you have write permission then update `readxl` again. See more here https://hpc.wsu.edu/programmers-guide/r/